# How to create element <a> in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I want to create some link in wicket application. I found there is class:       final

> BookmarkablePageLink link = new
>   BookmarkablePageLink("link", Page.class);

to create it. Here is just problem. I need to send some object to this page when I am creating it. I know there is `pageParamater` but this can send just string. Is there other way how to create link which open new web page with my own object ?

Comment: A normal Link with a `setResponsePage()` in the `onClick` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples especially at the links example http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/linkomatic/.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use Link component and you can pass an object to the target page wrapping it with a Model.

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
add(new Link(){
public void onClick(){
MyClass newClass = new MyClass(Parameters);
setResponsePage(MyClass);
}
});
```